# Android Reverse Playback and Frame by Frame

Tags: android, video, reverse, playback

I am trying to create an app with the following features:

- normal video playback
- slower video playback
- frame by frame
- reverse video playback (normal, slower, frame by frame)
- seekable to specific times
- video scrubbing
- no video sound needed
- video is recorded via the device's camera

The closest comparison to an app, would be the Ubersense Coach app for iOS and Coach's Eye on Android, though there are a few others, and they have all these features.

I have looked into several choices so far:

- First the built in Android Media Player, which can't really do anything I need.
- Then the MediaExtractor/decoder, looking through the code for Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), which can't play backwards.
- Tried to pull out each frame as needed with the MediaMetadataRetriever, which is too slow (100ms per frame) and the GC is in the way.
- Looked for a library that could potentially solve the issue, without luck so far.

With MediaExtractor I already have the ability to play back video, forward frame by frame or full speed. But I do not have that luxury in reverse, and the seeking does take some time since I need it without artifacts.

When trying to go in reverse, even trying to seek to a previous sync and advancing to the frame, before the one I currently had, it is not doable without huge lag (as expected).

I am wondering if there is a better codec I could use, or a library I have yet to stumble upon. And would rather avoid having to create something custom in native code if possible.

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Have you tried using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever?

Comment: I'm looking for similar libraries or workarounds, and I've just found [this article](http://andrey.chernih.me/2014/06/28/video-recording-and-processing-in-android/), which I haven't tried but I think it's nice to refer the `MediaCodec`.